# Doxygen C struct declaration without definition in header file

Tags: c, doxygen

Is it possible in Doxygen to add a brief description of a struct declared but not defined? For example, running `doxygen <config file>` (where `<config file>` is the configuration file with default parameters) in the folder with the file `mydefinition.h`

```
#ifndef MYDEFINITION_H_
#define MYDEFINITION_H_

/** My super secret structure you can't access fields */
struct MyStructure;

/** The function that lets you use any instance of 'struct MyStructure'
 * @param msobj the object
 */
void functionUsingMyStructure(struct MyStructure* msobj);
```

will generate the documentation of the functon but **not** the documentation of the structure.

I tried to modify the configuration file of Doxygen by setting `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES` but it doesn't change the situation.

Comment: Probably you will need something like \cond

Comment: Don't know if it is already solved, but I think the comand searched for is \struct (and not \cond)

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen ignores forward declarations of structs. To workaround this, you have to explicitly state that the given comment block describes your struct.

```
/** @struct MyStructure
 * My super secret structure you can't access fields
 */
struct MyStructure;
```